# Is there a way to prevent blowing incandescent bulbs from tripping the fuse/MCB?

Tags: electricity

As this is the main cause for MCB tripping in my home is there a way to prevent this from happening (either by lowering the voltage or being able to tell when a bulb is close to the burnout point?)

Edit:

I have reasons for using incandescent bulbs so switching to CFL/LED is not an option.

These are 60W branded bulbs (bought locally) used in a 240V 16A circuit.

Will Halogen bulbs be a better option?

To be clear - the MCB trips when I turn the light on and a bulb which was Ok before blows.

Comment: you might just need to reassess what's on the lighting circuit. Use CFLs or LED bulbs and you won't have this problem, for instance.

Comment: It's a very strange phenomena going there in your house. Normally the filament gets broken and it stops to glow. There is no logic behind your claims, there must be something wrong in your house wiring, but I have no idea what this could be.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the MCB make, model and rating as well as details (volt and watt ratings of your bulbs and a photo if you think it will help.

Comment: While it's not something I would have expected, some web searching suggests that this actually *does* sometimes happen; I'm finding claims that bulbs are supposed to be internally fused. Not sure if that is credible... but if so, it would suggest maybe the asker is buying cheap, substandard bulbs.  With the whole idea of incadescent lighting being deprecated and perhaps in places even banned, it seems plausible that factories still making them might eventually cut corners.

Comment: Occasionally filament bulbs do fail with a surge of high current : possibly an arc from vaporised wire. Solution : avoid filament bulbs.

Comment: And why exactly must you use filament bulbs?   If it's a particular unique application you might consider locally fusing or protecting that fixture; you could also look at some sort of soft-start circuit.  If it's a general thing, consider me skeptical that you really need to use them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a product usage question and lacks any details of the requirement which would permit engineering methods to be applied.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič there is a reason why a burned out light bulb would trip a breaker ... is is the same reason that a lightbulb will sometimes flash brightly when removing a burned out bulb without turning off power ... the free end of a broken filament contacts the opposite post due to vibration

Comment: I'm just curious about your reasons for not using CFL/ LED lamps. I have a friend that lives in a farm area and he has troubles with high voltage surge that about once in a year  ruins several CFL at once. He didnt have this problems when he used incandescent. At the time of transition from incandescet there were situations in that only CFL had failures.

Comment: The reason is light spectrum.

Comment: If you're willing to pay extra for them, you can now get LED bulbs to achieve pretty much any spectrum you'd like.  LED bulbs have come a long way.  You may wish to check out some high end ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When warmed up, a 100W incandescent bulb will draw 435mA on 230V which means a resistance of 529 ohms.

Adding a [20 ohms NTC](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/600/SL0320001-972851.pdf) resistor in series with the bulb should limit the current if the bulb fails at power-up and arcs. If the bulb lights up without failing, once the NTC is hot its resistance will be less than 1.5 ohms so it will have negligible losses. If the bulb fails when the NTC is hot there won't be any protection, but that's pretty rare. For 60W bulbs, adjust NTC value accordingly. You could use a [33 ohm](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/data_sheet/50/db/icl_16/S153.pdf) NTC.

Note the 10A circuit breaker on this specific light circuit should trip before the main circuit breaker, so the whole house shouldn't be in the dark.

But really, there are excellent inexpensive LEDs these days. I recommend these [CRI95 strips](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32948777264.html) in 3000K or 2400K and these [3000K >90CRI GU10 spots](https://www.osram.com/ecat/PARATHOM%20DIM%20PAR%2016-Professional%20LED%20reflector%20lamps-LED%20lamps-Lamps-Digital%20Systems/com/en/GPS01_2937410/PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat/ZMP_3237608/). Also this [forum topic](http://budgetlightforum.com/node/69805).

Answer (score 1):

You will have this problem with all 240V incandescent bulbs. The reason is 240V is enough to make a bulb arc wildly as soon the filament breaks, and those arcs tend to bridge the whole gap between both ends of the filament. That means thousands of amperes are rushing through the gap, enough to trip any breaker or fuse.

There are *Philips MASTERclassic* bulbs which have a tiny mains adapter and a 12V halogen bulb. They don't have this problem as the halogen bulb is current limited by the mains adapter. But I don't think they are available as 60W bulbs, as those get too hot to have electronics in the tiny space below the bulb.

Or you could wire a ballast coil originally meant for a fluorescent light in series with the light fixture. That one limits the current as well.

Comment: Is it the 240V itself or does this have to do with inductance of the wiring? Could an over-voltage device in parallel with the lamp possibly prevent the arc from forming in the first place? Or maybe just a capacitor?

Comment: Strangely I don't remember that it ever happened when until the last 10 years. Anyway could you explain more about the ballast coil solution?

Comment: @mkeith: The arcing is from mechanical failure of the filament on startup. But at 240V, the arc easily jumps the whole distance between both filament clamps once it is ignited.

Comment: @OMGsh: It could be that the bulbs you use have a mechanical design very prone to arcing. The smaller the bulb, the more likely.

Comment: I guess my question is, after the circuit breaker trips, if you reset the breaker and re-energize the circuit, does it trip again due to spontaneous arc formation? It sounds to me like some inductance is required to initiate the arc. If that is the case, then there is a possibility that some sort of transient voltage suppression could prevent arc formation in the first place.

Comment: @mkeith No, after the bulb burns out it burned, when the wire is torn I never get a short circuit.

Comment: OK, well there is hope for some type of circuit fix then. The other easy thing would be to put a fuse in series with the bulb so that the fuse can blow instead of tripping the breaker. You will just have to replace the fuse every time you replace a burnt out bulb. You might have to experiment to find a fuse which will blow before the breaker trips.

Answer (score 1):

Some bulbs are internally fused.  Many aren't, because the fuse costs money.  See if you can buy brands that do fit the fuse.

MCBs come in different speed ratings. "B" is the fastest, and often the one fitted by default.  "C" or "D" rated ones are slower to trip.  But only fit one if the wiring can handle a slower trip time.  UK wiring using "twin and earth" cable with an under-sized earth can be unsuitable for a slow MCB.